# Connecting studio monitors to DDJ-SB

Tags: speakers, dj, midi-controller-keyboard

I only have a DDJ-SB as I am jut starting out and having some fun. I have been looking for some cheapish monitors to buy and found the M-audio bx5 d2.

I am wondering how I would connect them to the controller as it only has a red/white. Do I need to buy anything other than the speakers or will they connect right out of the box?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The outputs of the DDJ-SB are RCA, and the inputs of the BX5 D2 are XLR and TRS (you can use either).

You can use a cable with a pair of RCA males and a pair of XLR or 1/4" TS (you use TS instead of TRS because the DDJ-SB's output is unbalanced). Like [this one](http://www.sweetwater.com/store/detail/CPR202/) or [a pair of this one](http://www.sweetwater.com/store/detail/XRM105).

You can also use a [dual RCA male - dual RCA male cable](http://www.sweetwater.com/store/detail/CRA201AU) and use a pair of RCA to XLR, or RCA to TRS, or RCA to TS adapters.